# iPhone - Problem with in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I've created iPhone app with in-app purchase.
Now, I'm in testing phase.

I created provisioning profile com.satyam.testapp
In iTunes connected I created the application and uploaded the images, screen shots, desscription etc. I also created two id's for in-app purchase. One is com.satyam.testapp.book1 and the other one is com.satyam.testapp.book5

I created test account also for verifying my in-app purchases.

Using com.stayam.testapp i created developer test profile and using the same in my developed application.

I logged out the itunes app store account in my iphone.

Now i started running my application on my iphone. Its saying that no items are there to purchase. But its not even asking me for credentials where i've to enter test account username and password.....

how to debug it?

Here's my delegate:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:response.products];
    for(int i=0;i<[myProduct count];i++)        
    {
        SKProduct *product = [myProduct objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Name: %@ - Price: %f",[product localizedTitle],[[product price] doubleValue]);      
        NSLog(@"Product identifier: %@", [product productIdentifier]);
    }       

    for(NSString *invalidProduct in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        NSLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@", invalidProduct);

    [request autorelease];
    [myProduct release];
}
```

Comment: Is your device jailbroken? If so, you need to revert the jailbreak for IAP to work.

Comment: @pocjoc When I upload the app to the app store will the IAP work for jailbroken to?

Comment: @m1sk Yes it does. It is only on the test environment that the InApp does not work fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check your SKProductsRequest call back, which will probably show that it is caused by an invalid product id, which unfortunately can be a pain to debug on the sandbox

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *items = response.products;

    for(SKProduct *item in items)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , item.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , item.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , item.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , item.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid Product title: %@" , item.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Invalid Product description: %@" , item.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Invalid Product price: %@" , item.price);
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
}
```

Assuming it is caused by an invalid product ID run through the following check list

- Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
- Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
- Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
- Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
- Have you configured your project to code sign using this new
  provisioning profile?
- Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above?
- Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?
- Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?
- Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?

Comment: I updated the description which has the delegate that I wrote. 1. In-app purchase for my app id is enabled. 2. Yes, I checked "Clared for sale" 3. Bundle ID matches app id. 4. yes, i created new prov profile for the new app id. 5. i'm using new profile to code sign. 6. i'm using 4.2 sdk for build and run on devices 7. i'm using full product id when requesting SKProductRequest. 8. I registered the product in itunes connect last week. 9. MY ITUNES CONNECT ACCOUNT IS NEW. BANK DETAILS ARE YET TO BE ADDED. I DON'T THINK ITS NECESSARY AS IT IS NECESSARY ONLY TO WITHDRAW MONEY.

Comment: I've found in the past that unless all the financial details are filled in, you will always get back that your product ids are invalid

Comment: The financial details are updated successfully now. Still I face the same issue.

Comment: delete and re setup your provisioning profile, you may find this clears it

Comment: great answer! My problem was trying to figure out why I do get items in simulator and not on the device. Removing the app and restarting xCode did the trick. This must be done every time you switch a box you develop on, it seems.

Comment: In my case, it worked after setting my contracts, tax, and banking information.

Comment: Last question "Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?" helped us to find our the culprit .Now properly fetching "response.products"

Answer (score 7):

Try deleting your app from the phone you are testing on, then "Build and Debug".

If that doesn't solve your problem, I would recommend going through the following blog post.

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: Working on a new version of my app I all the sudden started seeing this and got worried... your solution fixed mine and I wouldn't have thought of it on my own.  Deleted the app, cleaned, rebuilt.. done!

Comment: This worked for me. It turns out I was having this problem because of installing over a version of the app downloaded from the app store. This made it run in non-sandbox mode so none of my new sandbox-only IAP objects were showing up.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can login with your test account from where you logged out the existing one.
2- For debuging, you have to wait for your products (com.satyam.testapp.book1 and com.satyam.testapp.book5) to become valid. Currently your products have to be in response.invalidProductIdentifiers list. You'll be asked for your test account credentials when your products will be valid. Sometimes it takes some time for products to become valid and be sure you signed contracts for paid Apps.

Comment: Its almost 10 days when i created the products in app store itunes connect. i think they might be valid by this time. i'm getting response.invalidProductIdentifiers.

Comment: have you signed contracts for paid Apps?I had the same problem few weeks ago, my product was invalid and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

checkout whether your product id **"com.satyam.testapp.book1"** is same as the one you registered in your iTunes  store, and you checked the **"clear for sale"** option